# DynamicJasper API: not aligned border in PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

When the of a row of my reports gets too long for a single page, it gets continued on the next page, however, the border gets cut off as seen in this image.

Any ideas?

I'm using `JRPdfExporter` for exporting reports to PDF.

[image]

UPDATED:

```
        DynamicReport dynamicReport;
        ...
        fastReportBuilder.setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page.Page_A4_Landscape());
        fastReportBuilder.setUseFullPageWidth(true);

        //margin 50
        fastReportBuilder.setMargins(MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);

        fastReportBuilder.setDefaultStyles(getTitleStyle(), null, getColumnHeaderStyle(), getColumnDetailsStyle());

   private Style getColumnHeaderStyle() {
        Style hStyle = new Style();
        hStyle.setBorder(Border.THIN());
        hStyle.setTransparent(false);
        hStyle.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 142, 175));
        hStyle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        hStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        hStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        hStyle.setFont(new Font(10, MY_FONT, false));
        return hStyle;
    }

    private Style getColumnDetailsStyle() {
        Style cStyle = new Style();
        cStyle.setBorder(Border.THIN());
        cStyle.setFont(new Font(10, MY_FONT, false));
        cStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.TOP);
        return cStyle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Border Artifacts in JasperReport PDF Designed with iReport 5.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116882/border-artifacts-in-jasperreport-pdf-designed-with-ireport-5-1-0) gave me an idea.

I ended up extending the JRPdfExporter.  For some reason, when the data gets cut and continued on the next page, the cell box border's height and bottom where the data gets cut off are mismatched on its neighbor cell on the left.  To fix this, I'm storing the previous cell borders data, so when it reached the mismatched cell border data, it can be corrected.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRLineBox;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintElement;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;

import java.awt.*;

public class CustomPdfExporter extends JRPdfExporter {

    private float previousTop;
    private float previousHeight;
    private float prevY1;
    private float prevY2;

    private static final float FLOAT_ZERO = 0F;

    protected void exportBox(JRLineBox box, JRPrintElement element) {

        if (!isBoxVisible(box)) return;

        pdfContentByte.setLineCap(PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_PROJECTING_SQUARE);

        float x1 = element.getX() + getOffsetX();
        float y1 = jasperPrint.getPageHeight() - element.getY() - getOffsetY();
        float x2 = element.getX() + getOffsetX() + element.getWidth();
        float y2 = jasperPrint.getPageHeight() - element.getY() - getOffsetY() - element.getHeight();

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2, y1);

        if (previousTop == r.getTop() && previousHeight != r.getHeight()) {
            r.setBottom(prevY2);
        } else {
            prevY2 = y2;
            prevY1 = y1;
            previousHeight = r.getHeight();
            previousTop = r.getTop();
        }

        int borderFlag = 0;

        float lineWidth = 0;
        Color lineColor = null;

        if (box.getLeftPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO) {
            borderFlag |= Rectangle.LEFT;
            lineWidth = box.getLeftPen().getLineWidth().floatValue();
            lineColor = box.getLeftPen().getLineColor();
        }

        if (box.getTopPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO) {
            borderFlag |= Rectangle.TOP;
            if (lineWidth == 0) {
                lineWidth = box.getTopPen().getLineWidth().floatValue();
                lineColor = box.getTopPen().getLineColor();
            }
        }

        if (box.getRightPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO) {
            borderFlag |= Rectangle.RIGHT;
            if (lineWidth == 0) {
                lineWidth = box.getRightPen().getLineWidth().floatValue();
                lineColor = box.getRightPen().getLineColor();
            }
        }

        if (box.getBottomPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO) {
            borderFlag |= Rectangle.BOTTOM;
            if (lineWidth == 0) {
                lineWidth = box.getBottomPen().getLineWidth().floatValue();
                lineColor = box.getBottomPen().getLineColor();
            }
        }
        r.setBorder(borderFlag);
        r.setBorderColor(lineColor);
        r.setBorderWidth(lineWidth);

        pdfContentByte.rectangle(r);
        pdfContentByte.stroke();

        pdfContentByte.setLineDash(FLOAT_ZERO);
        pdfContentByte.setLineCap(PdfContentByte.LINE_CAP_ROUND);
    }

    private boolean isBoxVisible(JRLineBox box) {
        return box.getLeftPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO
                || box.getTopPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO
                || box.getRightPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO
                || box.getBottomPen().getLineWidth().floatValue() > FLOAT_ZERO
                ;
    }
}
```